# Julia - creating and printing graphs

Tags: graph, julia, graph-visualization

I'm using `LightGraphs.jl` package to work with graphs in Julia. I'm trying to pass all pairs `(i,j)` for which `z[i,j]=1` into a set of edges and corresponding `i` and `j` as nodes in the graph. Then I need to create a graph and get the output in a different figure. The following is what I've tried. But it doesn't create a graph or print it on the canvas. Here, `N=10`

```
for i in N
  for j in N
    if getvalue(z[i,j]) == 1
       push!(S, i)
       push!(S, j)
       print(S)
       fig = figure()
       G = Graph()
       add_edge!(G,i,j)
       add_vertices!(G,i)
       add_vertices!(G,j)
       t = TikzGraphs.plot(G)
       #TikzPictures.save(PDF("graph"), t)
       #TikzPictures.save(TEX("graph"), t)
    end
  end
end
```

Can someone please help me to get this correct?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you make an example that runs? Please provide the value of `z`, `S`, and any packages needed

Comment: Does `G = Graph(z) ; t = TikzGraphs.plot(G)` work? (no loops or anything. unsurprisingly, this transformation from adjacency matrix `z` to graph is quite common)

Comment: There are some good facilities for plotting LightGraphs in PlotRecipes.jl